# on start date value change, add 2 years to end date via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application's View Model class I have two felds Start date and end date.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
   public DateTime EndDate {get;set}
}
```

Here is code snippet from view

```
 @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
 @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.EndDate)
```

The Id and Name generated for StarDate and EndDate are "StartDate" & "EndDate" respectively.

Whenever the value of StartDate changes I want my EndDate's value to be StartDate + 2 year
So basically EndDate = StartDate + 2 years
This is what I have at the moment

```
<script>
    $("#StartDate").on('change',function() {
        var value = $("#StartDate").val();
        $("#EndDate").val() = value;
    });
</script>
```

I am already stuck at trying to set EndDate value to StartDate, in the line

```
 $("#EndDate").val() = value;
```

I get error saying `"L-value is expected"`

So, is there some simple way to achieve the result I explained?

The date format i have in textbox is **9/17/2015**

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It would be nice if someone could explain what the problem is with question when they downvote it. So that questions could be better quality next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
           <script>
                $("#StartDate").on('change',function() {
                    var value = $("#StartDate").val();
                   //assuming value in format of 12/01/2001 or 12/02/15
                    var current = value.slice(-2) //this gets the current year - "15"
                    var years = 2;
                    current = parseInt(current) + years // 15+2
                    value = value.slice(0,-2) //12/02/
                    value = value.toString().concat(current) //12/02/17

                    $("#EndDate").val(value); //this is how u set the value
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply looking for

```
$("#EndDate").val(value);
```

Reading the manual would've solved this issue quickly.

By doing

```
$("#EndDate").val() = value;
```

you're trying to call a method and then assign a value to the result which doesn't make sense, hence the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks that worked for setting the value, but any idea on how i can add years to it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try `$("#EndDate").val(value);` instead of `$("#EndDate").val() = value;`
2. For date format 9/17/2015, you can get EndDate value by:

   var m = value.match(new RegExp("(\\d+/\\d+/)(\\d+)"));

   var endDateValue = m[1] + (parseInt(m[2]) + 2);

Comment: I have added my date format in question at the end. would it not be possible to do it without moment.js?